# Linear transformation of homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We have 4 vector spaces $V_1$,$V_2$,$V_3$,$V_4$ and $f: V_1 \to V_2$ and $g: V_3 \to V_4$ are linear transformations.

Show that $_gF_f\colon\hom_k(V_2,V_3)\to\hom_k(V_1,V_4), h\mapsto  g*h*f $ is linear transformation.

In general we need to show $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$

But here I don't know how to start: we have an input $h$.
But because $h(x)$ belongs to $V_3$ how is it possible that, $f(h(x))$ is defined?

Comment: $V_1\xrightarrow{f}V_2\xrightarrow{h}V_3\xrightarrow{g}V_4$. You don't need $f(h(x))$, but $h(f(x))$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $h\in\hom(V_2,V_3)$, then $_gF_f(h)=g\circ h\circ f\in\hom(V_1,V_4)$. So, the problem is:

- Is it true that $_gF_f(h_1+h_2)=_gF_f(h_1)+_gF_f(h_2)$?
- Is it true that $_gF_f(\lambda h)=\lambda\times_gF_f(h)$?

And, yes, it is true.

Comment: What I got: $g(h(f(h_1 + h_2))) = g(h( f(h_1) + f(h_2) ))$. But we don't know, if $h$ is linear transformation or not. That is my problem

Comment: @yef_dan_92 You got it wrong. What you have to prove is that $g\bigl((h_1+h_2)\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\bigr)=g\bigl(h_1\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\bigr)+g\bigl(h_2\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\bigr)$.

Comment: Now it's clear! Thank you very much!